# AWS S3 File Location in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, data, amazon-s3, amazon-aws

I'm trying to create an automation in Marketing Cloud with a File Transfer and Import Activity that would run daily and read CSV files from an S3 location and save data in a Data Extension in SFMC.

I have the automation ready, I just need to create the File Location for Amazon Storage, but when I try to validate the File Location I see the following error

[image]

I tried to clarify with Salesforce Support and Amazon if this is a Salesforce issue or an Amazon issue and what would be the problem, but Salesforce was of no help so far (the second case opened today, the first one took almost a month with no result) and no solution proposed by the guys from Amazon worked so far.

Based on the error given I supposed some credentials are incorrect or some permission is missing on the AWS Side, but because there is no information on how to create these Credentials/Roles in Amazon in the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_overview_set_up_amazon_s3_location.htm&type=5) that Salesforce offers or if they should be related to a user, role or location, is hard to say for sure what the issue is.

Has anyone ever stumbled on this issue and knows what the problem is? Or at least if it's on the Salesforce side or on the Amazon side?

Any information is appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: It's an authorization error, so could be either side but more likely AWS side.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! Yes, we also think it may be an auth error, but all the credentials provided for S3 encountered the same issue. So it's either something else, or the team providing the credentials, doesn't know what to provide for this integration (and I don't know how to help them)